# Preloading images on IE7-IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom, cross-browser

**I tried two different techniques**:

```
url = 'http://domain.com/image.gif';
$('body').append('<img style="display:none" src="'+url+'" />');
```

and

```
image = Image(1,1);
image.src = 'http://domain.com/image.gif';
```

Images get preloaded in IE6, Chrome 8, Firefox 3.5+

**but cannot get these to work in IE8 or IE7**

---

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Don't set display:none - maybe IE is optimizing it some weird way; just don't append the image to the body and it will not show

Comment: @Andrey: the http calls are not showing up on my server, the image urls virtually change each time a page loads

Comment: Use Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) or the IE9 F12 Developer Tools' network tab to look for network requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [jQuery plugin](http://farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/) to do what you want.

Another way is to do your jQuery image processing only when the whole of the DOM, including the images themselves, has been loaded e.g. instead of

```
$(window).ready(function(){.....
```

use

```
$(window).load(function(){.....
```

See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event).

Comment: The point here is that this plugin has a couple of callback functions which are called a) when an image is loaded and ready to manipulate (e,g, obtain its height/width etc) and b) when all the images have been loaded and ready to be manipulated.